# Flash360 rotator giving Error 2032 on server

Tags: javascript, html, xml, flash

I have a flash rotators for a website i am doing for a client.
I am able to view and use them if i load them off my computer. 
But as soon as i load them on to any of my servers and try to access them i am presented with an IO error 2032
Now i know this means it cant find the files it needs to load so i then changed all the links to absolutes when it was calling for the necessary files and i still get the error. 
I have also checked all folder permissions and their all good.
I am at a loss to wht maybe the problem.

here is a link were i just put all the rotators up to view
http://honeyword.mybigcommerce.com/pages/Clickers

file structure
Mainfolder
  
Viewer
   
**_*html files (for each product)*
   
_swfobject21.js
   
 _*expressInstall.swf*
   
_ImageRotator.swf
   
_*Products*
      
__***Folders(producname)*
        
____*config.xml*
        
____*Images*
         
__*_*__.png

any help would be appreciated.

thank you

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be an error related to file or folder permissions: I get a 403 Forbidden error page when accessing the file in the error message directly (I copied the filename from the first of the error messages below the "checking..." field and just pasted it in a new browser window).

Comment: I thought that was the problem as well until i uploaded it to another server giving everything full permissions and it still gave the above error. [Second server](http://freshexpressiongraphics.com/honeyword/Viewer/basketball.html)

Comment: This time, the file does not exist (404): http://freshexpressiongraphics.com/honeyword/Viewer/Products/basketball/Images/image001.jpg